# ECMAScriptのみに準拠したライブラリの探し方

Tags: javascript

ECMAScriptのみに依存した（DOMやブラウザの仕様を除く）ライブラリを探す方法を知りたいです。
具体的には、ブラウザやECMAScriptエンジンで使いまわせるようなものです。UIが絡まない、純粋な演算のみで成り立っているようなものであればあるだろうと思うのですが、いかがでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

例えば「何かに依存しているもの＝グローバルで定義された何かを利用している」という仮説が成り立つとすると、

「.jshintrcファイルでglobalsに何も指定せずにjshintを実行すれば、依存ライブラリがグローバルで定義したもの、つまり対象のライブラリ内で宣言されていないグローバルなものを利用している、という意味の警告が出る」

と思います。例えば、調査対象のライブラリに対してjshintを実行した際に、jQueryを使っていれば「$が宣言されていない」と出るでしょうし、AngularJS1に依存してれば「angularが宣言されていない」と出るかと（もちろん依存ライブラリまでセットでjshint実行しては意味ないです）。

もし警告が出なければ「特に依存ライブラリはなさそう」という可能性が高い、と言っても良さそうです。確実な方法ではないですが、判断材料としては使えるかと思います。